# How to handle delay in message delivery in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I am developing a chat application using `Twisted` framework in Python. However, sometimes the messages are delivered with a huge delay of upto 2 minutes from server to client.

Any idea what could be the reason for this delay ? Is this related to slower network ?

```
class MultiClientEcho(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        ip = self.transport.getPeer().host

    def dataReceived(self, data):   
        print "data is " + data
        client.transport.write(data)    

class MultiClientEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiClientEcho(self)

def main():
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiClientEchoFactory())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything in your example server code that would introduce additional delays in data transfer.  Can you actually reproduce the problem using this server?  What code is the client running?